# Generate different artifacts based on operating system for Maven using profiles

Tags: maven, build

I am trying to generate different artifacts based on OS used using profiles but when I run **mvn validate**, it gives me following errors

1. Unrecognised tag: 'profiles' (position: START_TAG seen ...\r\n        ... C:\test-app\pom.xml, line 33, column 19
2. Unknown packaging: nar @ line 15, column 16

My POM.xml is given below. **nar-maven-plugin** is common between two OS.

I could not figure out what is the issue here. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<project
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvn-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.company.mvn-test</groupId>
<artifactId>test-app</artifactId>
<packaging>nar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.mvn-test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-library</artifactId>
        <type>nar</type>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>integration-test</defaultGoal>
    <profiles>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
                <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <libraries>
                        <library>
                            <type>executable</type>
                            <run>true</run>
                        </library>
                    </libraries>
                    <linker>
                        <name>g++</name>
                    </linker>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <profile>
            <id>OS1</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>Windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <copy todir="bin" flatten="true">
                                        <fileset dir="target">
                                            <include name="**/*dll"/>
                                        </fileset>
                                    </copy>
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>OS2</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>unix</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <copy todir="bin" flatten="true">
                                        <fileset dir="target">
                                            <include name="**/*so"/>
                                            <include name="**/*test-app"/>
                                        </fileset>
                                    </copy>
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</build>
```

Comment: Move profiles out of `<build>` tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvn-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.company.mvn-test</groupId>
<artifactId>test-app</artifactId>
<packaging>nar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.mvn-test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-library</artifactId>
        <type>nar</type>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>integration-test</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
            <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <libraries>
                    <library>
                        <type>executable</type>
                        <run>true</run>
                    </library>
                </libraries>
                <linker>
                    <name>g++</name>
                </linker>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>OS1</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>Windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <copy todir="bin" flatten="true">
                                        <fileset dir="target">
                                            <include name="**/*dll"/>
                                        </fileset>
                                    </copy>
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>OS2</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>unix</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <copy todir="bin" flatten="true">
                                        <fileset dir="target">
                                            <include name="**/*so"/>
                                            <include name="**/*test-app"/>
                                        </fileset>
                                    </copy>
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
</project>
```